# Custom Query JPA MongoRepository with optional parameter

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data-jpa

I have this `ticket` document in Mongo Database

```
private id;
...
private EnumState state;
private EnumType type;
private EnumPriority priority;
```

Now my requirement is filtered by these fields in a http request with API

1. `http://localhost:8080/` - get all without filter
2. `http://localhost:8080?state=1` get all documents where state equal 1
3. `http://localhost:8080?state1&type=1` get all documents where state equal 1 and type equal 1
4. `http://localhost:8080?state1&type=1&priority=1` get all documents where state equal 1 and type equal 1 and priority equal 1.

I am using JPA MongoRepository interface and writing a Custom Query

```
@Query("{ $and: [ " +
        "{ $or: [ { 'state': { $eq: ?0 } }, { 'state': { $exists: false } } ] }, " +
        "{ $or: [ { 'type': { $eq: ?1 } }, { 'type': { $exists: false } } ] }, " +
        "{ $or: [ { 'priority': { $eq: ?2 } }, { 'priority': { $exists: false } } ] }" +
        "] }")
Page<Ticket> findAllBy(IncidentState state, IncidentType type, IncidentPriority priority, Pageable p);
```

But for example when call `http://localhost:8080/` and `http://localhost:8080?state=1` is always return me Ticket[].

Comparing with PL/SQL I need something like

```
select * from ticket where
(i_type is null or type=i_type) and
(i_state is null or state=i_state) and
(i_priority is null or priority=i_priority)
```

What is wrong in my @Query definition ?

Answer (score 0):

After one day on possible workaround's I found other implementation.

For a better control on Mongo query and operations I switch from MongoRepository to MongoTemplate and create mt custom methods with Criteria for parameters filters and validations, and TextCriteria for text search.